# Alt text on images: alt="" vs. alt

Tags: html, accessibility

When specifying empty alt text on an image, is there any difference to screen reader users if the alt is rendered as `alt` or if is rendered as `alt=""` in the HTML?

Comment: No, there's no difference. Both are ignored. It's empty. That's what matters.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same? Similar situation to when you do `required` compared to `required="required"`?

Comment: @AndyHolmes — `required` is a boolean attribute, `alt` is not.

Comment: @AndyHolmes not exacly. `required` and `required="required"` are both accepted as *Required*, while having `alt` is like not having it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - I'm not sure that's correct. NVDA treats alt and alt="" the same (ignoring the image completely); whereas an image without any alt is read as "blank" - so it's not quite the same as not having it.